# IPC mechanism for telephone conversation using Unix domain sockets

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ipc

I am implementing the IPC for a telephonic conversation.Created two files :receiver.c and caller.c..
The rc.h contains all the include files.I am testing out the use of Unix domain sockets according to FIFO's ..
The caller.c file is :

```
#include "rc.h"
int main()
{
    int sock_fd;
    struct sockaddr_un unix_addr;
    char buf[2048];
    int n;
    if ((sock_fd=socket(AF_UNIX,SOCK_STREAM,0))<0)
    {
        perror("cli:socket()");
        exit(1);
    }
    unix_addr.sun_family=AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(unix_addr.sun_path,SERVER);
    if (connect(sock_fd,(struct sockaddr *) &unix_addr,
        sizeof(unix_addr.sun_family)+
        sizeof(unix_addr.sun_path))< 0)
    {
        perror("cli:connect()");
        exit(1);
    }
    sprintf(buf,"Reciever called by receiver");
    n=strlen(buf)+1;
    if (write (sock_fd,buf,n)!=n)
    {
        perror("cli:write()");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Caller sent-->%s",buf);
    if ((n=read(sock_fd,buf,2047))<0)
    {
        perror("cli:read()");
        exit(1);
    }
    buf[n]=0;
    while (buf[n]==0){n--;}
    if (buf[n]=='\n')
        buf[n]='\0';
    printf("Reciever received<--%s \n",buf);
    exit(0);
}
```

The receiver.c is:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include "rc.h"

static void stop(int n)
{
    unlink(SERVER);
    exit(0);
}

static void receiver()
{
    int sock_fd,cli_sock_fd;
    struct sockaddr_un unix_addr;
    char buf[2048];
    int n,addr_len;
    pid_t pid;
    char *pc;

    signal(SIGINT,stop);
    signal(SIGQUIT,stop);
    signal(SIGTERM,stop);
    unix_addr.sun_family=AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(unix_addr.sun_path,SERVER);
    addr_len=sizeof(unix_addr.sun_family)+strlen(unix_addr.sun_path);
    unlink(SERVER);
    if (bind(sock_fd,(struct sockaddr *)&unix_addr,addr_len)<0)
    {
        perror("Receiver:bind()");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (listen(sock_fd,5)<0)
    {
        perror("Receiver:caller()");
        unlink(SERVER);
        exit(1);
    }
    while ((cli_sock_fd=accept(sock_fd,(struct sockaddr*)&unix_addr,&addr_len))>=0)
    {
        if ((n=read(cli_sock_fd,buf,2047))<0)
        {
            perror("Receiver:read()");
            close(cli_sock_fd);
            continue;
        }
        buf[n]='\0';
        for(pc=buf;*pc!='\0' && (*pc<'0' || *pc>'9');pc++);
        pid=atol(pc);
        if (pid!=0)
        {
            sprintf(buf,"Receiver called by caller\n",pid);
            n=strlen(buf)+1;
            if (write(cli_sock_fd,buf,n)!=n)
                perror("Receiver:write()");
        }
        close(cli_sock_fd);
    }
    perror("Receiver:accept()");
    unlink(SERVER);
    exit(1);
}

int main()
{
    int r;
    if ((r=fork())==0)
        receiver();
    if(r<0)
    {
        perror("Receiver:fork()");
        exit(1);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Now the problem occurs while compiling where i am getting:

```
sourajyoti@ubuntu:~/os2$ gcc receiver.c -o test1
receiver.c: In function ‘stop’:
receiver.c:6:9: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\s' [enabled by default]
receiver.c: In function ‘receiver’:
receiver.c:23:28: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\s' [enabled by default]
receiver.c:25:9: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\s' [enabled by default]
receiver.c:34:10: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\s' [enabled by default]    
receiver.c:58:9: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\s' [enabled by default]
```

Then after this:

```
sourajyoti@ubuntu:~/os2$ ./test1
Receiver:bind(): Bad file descriptor
```

Same for client:

```
sourajyoti@ubuntu:~/os2$ gcc caller.c -o test2    
caller.c: In function ‘main’:    
caller.c:15:28: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\s' [enabled by default]    
sourajyoti@ubuntu:~/os2$ ./test2    
cli:connect(): No such file or directory
```

The header file rc.h is:

```
     #include <sys/types.h>
     #include <sys/socket.h>
     #include <sys/un.h>
     #include <sys/ipc.h>
     #include <sys/msg.h>
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <errno.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>
     #include <unistd.h>
     #define SERVER "\tmp\server"
```

Comment: pat answered you,but i have a good solution for using /temp, use `mktemp function` . `man 3 mktemp`

Comment: Can you elaborate?I am new to this..

Comment: \s i have managed to change..However the bind remains a problem.i can't understand why the socket fails to create??

Comment: What did you change `SERVER` to?  Did you add a call to `socket()` in the receiver?

Answer (score 0):

Your `SERVER` macro has an illegal `'\s'` escape sequence.  Unfortunately, you don't show the contents of your headers, so I can't see the definition.

Your receiver doesn't actually create a socket.  It just binds an uninitialized `sock_fd`, which is causing it to fail.

The client fails because the receiver never created a socket to which it can connect.

EDIT

Ok, now I can see the definition of `SERVER`, I see that you are using backslashes instead of forward slashes in your path name.

In the receiver, you still need to create a socket, with code similar to that in the client:

```
if ((sock_fd=socket(AF_UNIX,SOCK_STREAM,0))<0)
{
    perror("Receiver:socket()");
    exit(1);
}
```

Normally, when I `bind` a UNIX domain socket, I just give `sizeof(unix_addr)` as the address length:

```
if (bind(sock_fd,(struct sockaddr *)&unix_addr,sizeof(unix_addr))<0)
{
    perror("Receiver:bind()");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: I have uploaded the rc.h file.

Comment: \s i have managed to change..However the bind remains a problem.i can't understand why the socket fails to create??

Answer (score 0):

Already i said , pat answered you , but i'm saying about using `mktemp`:

```
       char sfn[15] = "";
       FILE *sfp;

       strlcpy(sfn, "/tmp/ed.XXXXXX", sizeof sfn);
       if (mktemp(sfn) == NULL || (sfp = fopen(sfn, "w+")) == NULL) {
               fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", sfn, strerror(errno));
               return (NULL);
       }
       return (sfp);
```

should be rewritten like this:

```
       char sfn[15] = "";
       FILE *sfp;
       int fd = -1;

       strlcpy(sfn, "/tmp/ed.XXXXXX", sizeof sfn);
       if ((fd = mkstemp(sfn)) == -1 ||
           (sfp = fdopen(fd, "w+")) == NULL) {
               if (fd != -1) {
                       unlink(sfn);
                       close(fd);
               }
               fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", sfn, strerror(errno));
               return (NULL);
       }
       return (sfp);
```

Comment: The goal is to create a UNIX domain socket with a name that is known to both the client and the server.  This code creates a file with a name that is known only to this program.

Comment: pat, i said before, i only want to help about how to use `/temp` , if you want to use write socket daemon, please separate socket from daemon. google for how to write daemon ,  i suggest : http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html , and read more about TCP or UDP , because i don't know about your project, some project needs UDP and some needs TCP.

Comment: for your socket user POSIX therad , named `ptherad`